# Using Pandas & Matplotlib to make a chart, but change the x axis values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I am struggling to understand how to rename the x axis values so they are dates, not numbers from 0 - 35.

It looks like the x axis it taking its values from the index column by default. I assume I need to add some code to change this, but im not sure how I go about doing that. Please may someone assist.

Here is the graph currently.

[image]

And some of the data table used here

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_orders = pd.read_csv("discount_fullprice_orders.csv")

df_orders.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe `df_orders.set_index('Date').plot.bar()`? Pandas typically uses the index for the x-values.

Comment: Oh thanks, Johan, that worked. Man, it really was that simple huh? hahaha

Answer (score 0):

label(___,Name,Value) modifies the label appearance using one or more name-value pair arguments. For example, 'FontSize',12 sets the font size to 12 points. Specify name-value pair arguments after all other input arguments. Modifying the label appearance is not supported for all types of charts.

sharpdetail

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).